# how do i make more than 1 slideshow gallery in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to make a slideshow gallery for my project, then i found this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow_gallery.asp it worked actually but only for 1 slideshow gallery, when i try to make the second one, it didn't work like i expected, it doesn't make 2 slideshow gallery my code just make the duplicate of the first one here is my code:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Position the image container (needed to position the left and right arrows) */

.container {
  position: relative;
}


/* Hide the images by default */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* Container for image text */

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Six columns side by side */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
}


/* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
    <img src="pict/paskib1.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
    <img src="pict/paskib2.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
    <img src="pict/paskib3.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
    <img src="pict/paskib4.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 6</div>
    <img src="pict/paskib5.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">6 / 6</div>
    <img src="pict/paskib6.jpeg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="pict/paskib1.jpeg" style="width:100%; height : 37px" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="PASKIBRA - SMK PGRI 11 CILEDUG">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="pict/paskib2.jpeg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="PASKIBRA - SMK PGRI 11 CILEDUG">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="pict/paskib3.jpeg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="PASKIBRA - SMK PGRI 11 CILEDUG">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="pict/paskib4.jpeg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="PASKIBRA - SMK PGRI 11 CILEDUG">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="pict/paskib5.jpeg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="PASKIBRA - SMK PGRI 11 CILEDUG">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="pict/paskib6.jpeg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="PASKIBRA - SMK PGRI 11 CILEDUG">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, you gived the code for only 1 slideshow here. Can you put the code for the second slideshow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simple duplicate your html code. If you want control each gallery with same javascript code you have to wrap your html gallary into a container element with an unique identfier. Here an idea:

```
<div id="gallery01">
<!-- Put your html code for gallery here -->
</div>

<div id="gallery02">
<!-- Put your html code for gallery here -->
</div>
```

Then you have to change your javascript main function so, that you pass theses id.
Example:

```
 function showSlides(currentClickobj, n) {
  var containerElement = getParentContainer(currentCklickObj);
  var i;

  /* Replace in your code `document.' by 'containerElement.' */
  var slides = containerElement.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots =containerElement.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = containerElement.getElementById("caption");
  ...
}
```

Because you don't use jquery you need a function that returns the container element.

```
 getParentContainer(childNode) {
  /* Put your code here */
}
```